# How can i set a jFrame to be always on top and focuse enabled until it is closed?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

There are two different Frames in my program and the second one open when i click the jButton is the first frame,so when the second frame is opened, I want the second frame to be always on top and focused until it is close. user can't be allowed to do anything in the first window until the second window is closed. how can i do this?

Comment: Cheka out [How to use dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Answer (score 33):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
frame.setAlwaysOnTop (true);
```

If you want frame to be always focused, you probably need to use modal dialog instead of JFrame:

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog ();
dialog.setModal (true);
dialog.setAlwaysOnTop (true);
dialog.setModalityType (ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```