# Keeping constant keyboard focus on application

Tags: java, keyboard, focus

I'm trying to create an application, which will be always on top and always receiving keyboard input. There was no problem with setting the Jframe on top (setAlwaysOnTop(true)), but I have some problems with the keyboard. Whenever a windows popouts (for instance Windows update or AV update), although the JFrame is still on top it looses keyboard focus. Even minimizing & maximizing (with alt + tab) doesn't help and I need to shut down and rerun the application. Is there any elegant and simple way to set pernament keyboard focus on the JFrame? I'm starting the application through the command line.

Thanks in advance for Your help :)

Comment: look this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795995/how-can-i-set-a-jframe-to-be-always-on-top-and-focuse-enabled-until-it-is-closed

Comment: Hi :) I tested the method mentioned in that topic, but it doesn't work well for me. After minimizing & maximizing application (with alt + tab) the keyboard input still stops working. On my machine there is no problem with it, however on the one where the program will be installed, the problem occurs. Both PC's have Windows 7 (mine 64 bit, another one is 32 bit). My computer has lower version of JRE. Can it cause problems? If not, is there any other way to make it work ? Thanks in advance for Your answer :)